# taking a screenshot of some element in the html

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, google-maps-api-3, screenshot

So I was wondering, if I have a div which contains a maps of google maps rendered with some makers and I want to take a picture of that element how can I do this?.I found [this solutions](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/webpage_thumbnailer.aspx) it's a approach of what I need but the problem it's that sending a url doesn't help me, I need the specific Div with all the markers. For the server side i'm using C# and for the cliente, asp.net with jquery. Also the google maps apiV3 to handle the maps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `Canvas2Image` library by Nihilogic Labs:

http://www.nihilogic.dk/labs/canvas2image/

Here's an example of how to take a screenshot of an element through JavaScript:

```
var oCanvas = document.getElementById("thecanvas");    
Canvas2Image.saveAsPNG(oCanvas);
```

**EDIT**

You might also take a look at `Html2Canvas` and `FlashCanvas` too. I believe one of them has support for earlier browsers (those which don't support HTML5).

Comment: Hi and thanks for asking. can't use html 5 i need to give support to all browsers incluing IE

Comment: well, after a lot of read, code and test html would be the option

Answer (score 1):

Use the method in the link you mentioned and crop the resulting image to the dimensions of your div.  You can use `myDiv.getBoundingClientRect()` in JavaScript to get the dimensions of your div.

Using the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx), you can manipulate the document using html or JavaScript to get the page in the state you need to take your screenshot.

Comment: Hi, and thanks asking the link doesn't solve my problem because the map picture depends the some behaviour which it's not injected in the url

Comment: Using the [WebBrowser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx), you can manipulate the document.  Look at the properties and methods available in `WebBrowser.Document`.  Of particular use may be `WebBrowser.Document.InvokeScript()`.  You can manipulate the html or run JavaScript to get the document in the state you need to create your screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the [Google Maps Static API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/staticmaps/) - this will render a map image, with markers on it, as a PNG.

Comment: ok, but how can i send the parameters all the markers in the map and the map itself?? is there a way to do this?